# вставить значение в массив байт

Tags: python

Есть массив байт.

```
b'\xa2\x01&\x04H\x16\x17"\x17\xf8\xf7\xa6X'
```

Пытаюсь вставить в начало

```
b'\xd2\x84M'
```

Ожидаю на выходе получить

```
b'\xd2\x84M\xa2\x01&\x04H\x16\x17"\x17\xf8\xf7\xa6X'
```

Пытался перевести все это в строку объединить и обратно в байты но это очевидно не правильно, подскажите как правильно получить конечный результат?

Comment: если эти значения в a и b, то `a+b`

Comment: Нужно приводить в вопросе код, как вы пытались "вставить в начало".

Answer (score 1):

Ничего не нужно никуда переводить, можно просто сложить в желаемом порядке:

```
b1 = b'\xa2\x01&\x04H\x16\x17"\x17\xf8\xf7\xa6X'
b2 = b'\xd2\x84M'
b3 = b2 + b1
print(b3)
```

Вывод:

```
b'\xd2\x84M\xa2\x01&\x04H\x16\x17"\x17\xf8\xf7\xa6X'
```